# Creating a List based on another List to reduce memory usage

Tags: scala, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

If I call some external library that returns a `List[LargeObjects]`, which is a list with objects that have a lot of fields, this will take a good chunk of heap memory. However, I am only interested in the `name` (String) field of each element. So, if I have this code:

```
externalLib.getLargeObjects.map(e => e.name) match {
  case l: List[String] =>
    ???
  case _ =>
    ???
}
```

Would JVM GC (at some point) free the memory taken by `List[LargeObjects]` (since it is dereferenced and not used after the `name` list is created) thus allowing me to have more free memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would JVM GC (at some point) free the memory taken by
>   `List[LargeObjects]` (since it is dereferenced and not used after the
>   name list is created) thus allowing me to have more free memory?

If no one is referencing the big list, and you only project the strings from these large objects, then the JVM will collect them once something triggers a GC in the generation storing them.

When the GC walks up the live objects graph, it will see that there are live references to your `String` objects. As for the list, if no one is referencing it, it will consider it dead and collect it.